# SQL return distinct values and their combined count in one query

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

Using MySQL and am supposed to return the number of absentees and their names. I do a query for all students and subtract the subquery of ones who showed up that day.

Is this even possible to do in 1 query? I know how to do it with 2 separate ones and they return statements of different sizes so I'm not sure these are compatible.

For list of names:

```
select distinct name 
from submissions join hacker
on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
where name not in
(
  select distinct name 
from submissions join hacker
on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
where sub_date = '2019-12-07'  
  )
```

For count:

```
select count(name) 
from submissions join hacker
on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
where name not in
(
  select distinct name 
from submissions join hacker
on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
where sub_date = '2019-12-07'  
  )
```

Comment: Hi @user2415706 please provide sample data and expected output if possible.

Comment: Hi @user2415706 You can combine this by using GROUP BY clause as per assumption and possible to combine this query after getting sample data.

Comment: The count would normally be resolved in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to perform the query once, then use `UNION` to combine the count and names into a single result.

```
WITH absentees as (select distinct name 
    from submissions join hacker
    on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
    where name not in
    (
      select distinct name 
    from submissions join hacker
    on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
    where sub_date = '2019-12-07'  
    )
)
SELECT * FROM absentees
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM absentees
```

This will put the total as the last line in the result.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is this style of writing the CTE equivalent? It is easier for me to read and remember with the entire CTE inside of a parentheses.

```With absentees AS (select distinct name 
    from submissions join hacker
    on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
    where name not in
    (
      select distinct name 
    from submissions join hacker
    on submissions.hacker_id=hacker.hacker_id
    where sub_date = '2019-12-07'  
    ))```

Comment: No, that was a mistake. I don't actually use CTEs much.